# Kafka MirrorMaker2 topics - replication factor

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am testing kafka mirror maker 2 in my local. Running 2 zookeepers and 2 kafka brokers. They are running as individual instance. So, 2 clusters in my local with 1 broker on each cluster. The brokers are running fine. Now, when i tries running the mirror maker on my local, running into the following issues.

```
[2020-02-14 16:58:18,371] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-2, groupId=dest-mm2] Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:290)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while attempting to create/find topic(s) 'mm2-offsets.dest.internal'
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:262)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore$1.run(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.start(KafkaBasedLog.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore.start(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.start(Worker.java:186)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.startServices(AbstractHerder.java:121)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:277)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:229)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
[2020-02-14 16:58:18,371] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=source-mm2] Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:290)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while attempting to create/find topic(s) 'mm2-offsets.source.internal'
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:262)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore$1.run(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.start(KafkaBasedLog.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore.start(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.start(Worker.java:186)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.startServices(AbstractHerder.java:121)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:277)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:229)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
```

This error is happening since there is only one broker in my local and mirror maker is trying to create offset topics with replication factor 3. How can I set the config to change the replication factor to 1.

I tried as below, but still the same error. not sure what is the correct config.

**mm2.properties**

```
# mm2.properties 
name=source->dest 
clusters=source, dest

source.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9091 
dest.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

source->dest.enabled=true

topics=test-3 groups=test-6-group 
offsets.storage.replication.factor=1
source.replication.factor=1 
dest.replication.factor=1

mm2-offsets.source.internal.replication.factor=1 
mm2-offsets.dest.internal.replication.factor=1
```

Comment: Did you try just setting 'replication.factor=1' instead of source/dest? Mirror maker will only be creating a topic in one of the locations so the replication factor should not affect both source and destination.

Comment: There's more than one file for MM2, right? Have you looked over the default properties?

Comment: By the way, 2 kafka clusters can use 1 zookeeper cluster

Answer (score 3):

It works after adding the below 2 props.

```
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1
```

Answer (score 2):

The setting is 'offset' (singular)

Use:

`offset.storage.replication.factor=1`

instead of:

`offsets.storage.replication.factor=1`

... did the trick for me